# When to switch over from Point to Point vs All to All communication?

Tags: mpi

Here's my problem. I have a parallel code that uses MPI for message passing. Each process has N buffers that contain messages to be sent to each other process, and N buffers that need to be filled with incoming data, N being the total number of processes in the MPI communicator. The send and receive buffers have different lengths (though  i sends to j the same amount of data that j sends to i). The length can be as high as several 100 kB, to as small as 0. Sometimes, only a relative small fractions of the buffers contain data (say less that 5%), but sometimes most buffers contain some data.
Right now, I have implemented the exchange using non blocking sends/blocking receives on the nonempty buffers. My question is ***at what point it becomes efficient to switch to a call to an AllToAll send/receive***. The number of processes can be as high as a few thousands, or as small as 2 or three, depending on the overall size of the problem.

Comment: In your case, that would be `MPI_Alltoallv()` but only if all the tasks know exactly how much data they will be sent. Collective make the code more compact (readable/maintainable) and performance wise, you let the MPI library take care of that for you. If you do not trust MPI libraries w.r.t. collective performance, then keep re-inventing better wheels.

Comment: Switching for my current configuration to `MPI_Alltoallv()` was rather easy. All I had to do was to merge the individual buffers into a single one, and creating the stride array. I ran some tests on our cluster. It appears that when using a relatively small number of cores (= large amount of data is from a core to itself), using nonblocking sends/blocking receives on the inter-cores part is faster. When using large amount of cores, (= smaller fraction of intra-core communication) AllToAll is better. The difference is usually no larger than a a factor two.